# Big Sur - Archive error in xcode12 for pod sparkle

Tags: xcode12, macos-big-sur, sparkle

Before updating to big sur my project worked without any problem...
After updating I keep getting errors saying

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SUUpdater
and
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

I'm using pod --> sparkle for updating my program.

Is there any solution for this???

I have tried deleting sparkle and reinstalling + rebooting mac + cleaning up build folder + restarting xcode.. none of it helped.

[image][image]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue when trying to build a release build of getfluency.io with Xcode 12. It seems to be related to the fact that Xcode now compiles releases for the arm64 architecture in addition to x86_64, since the new M1 macs use arm64 instead of x86. I'm guessing the library Sparkle vends with their cocoapod wasn't compiled for arm64. Going to look into it and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This same error was happening for me in release builds of [Fluency](https://getfluency.io) when using Sparkle v1.22.0. I updated to 1.24.0 via Cocoapods and it doesn't happen for me anymore, so I'm guessing there was some work done at some point between those versions which made Sparkle work correctly with arm64 architectures (for the new M1 devices). Discussion about it on Sparkle's github page: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/1620